# sql server how could be a char ',' be a numeric when use ISNUMERIC()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table in  witch a column "Value" is varchar I need convert the column  "CurrentValue" to float or decimal so first I valid if the column "CurrentValue" has a numeric but is no validating for example some rows has this type of data

```
Row No.   art                  CurrentValue isnumeric   Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
--------- -------------------- ------------ ----------- ------- 
1         109A00054            ,            1           ,
2         109A00054            ,            1           ,
3         109A00054            ,            1           ,
```

When I use the function isnumeric returns true my question is how could be a char ',' be numeric?

This is my query

```
select art, 
    value as [CurrentValue],
    isnumeric(i.Valor) as [isnumeric],
    case 
      when isnumeric(((ISNULL(NULLIF(i.Valor, ''), '0')))) = 1 then ISNULL(NULLIF(i.Valor, ''), '0')
      else '0'
    end as [Value]
    from A
```

- **[CurrentValue varchar(100)]**: is the raw value of the column
- **[isnumeric]**: is the result of the function isnumeric()
- **[Value]**: is a column where i try to convert all rows to a numeric value if the [CurrentValue] has a non numeric value will be converter as '0'

I run a test with this querys

```
      SELECT ISNUMERIC('Hello world!'); --result: 0
      SELECT ISNUMERIC('2345'); --result: 1
      SELECT ISNUMERIC(','); --result: 1 ' WTF!!!'
```

what I messing the docs doesn't say to much (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) except may sql sever think is decimal but any way

My question is how convert all values from varchar to numeric (any type of numeric It doesn't matter!) in a safe manner without errors

Comment: There are many discussions about isnumeric failings you can find with simple searching. The best answer is to change your schema and store numeric values in a numeric datatype. Absent that, use try_convert as suggested.

Comment: A "few" examples @SMor alludes to: [Fifteen Things I Hate About ISNUMERIC](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/02/fifteen-things-hate-isnumeric/), [Is It Time To Stop Using IsNumeric()?](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/time-stop-using-isnumeric/). [Stop using ISNUMERIC, it’s (probably) wrong](https://wp.larnu.uk/stop-using-isnumeric-its-probably-wrong/), [Why IsNumeric() is no good](https://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Why%20IsNumeric%20is%20no%20good.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of worrying about the problems with `ISNUMERIC()`, just say "No".  Use the `try_` functions instead:

```
select art, value as [CurrentValue],
       (case when try_convert(float, i.Valor) is not null then 1 else 0 end) as [isnumeric],
       (case when try_convert(float, i.Valor) is not null then i.Valor
             else '0'
        end) as [Value]
from A;
```

This uses `float` because it accepts most number formats.  For your particular purpose, you might want to use `int` or some other number type.